# Composite Simpson's Rule in C

Tags: c, math, for-loop, formula, equation

I'm trying to program Composite Simpson's Rule in C. The formula is:

[image]

where `x_j=a+jh` for `j=0, 1, ..., n-1`, `n` with `h=(b-a)/n`; in particular, `x_0=a` and `x_n=b`.

For some reason, the first and second loop have the same value. I checked over this a lot of times, but I can't seem to find my mistake.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float f(float);
float a;
float b;
float x;
float h;
int n;
int j;


 a=0;
 b=2;
 n=8;
 h = (n - j) / b; 

float first;
float second;
int main() {


  sum = (h / 3.0f) * (f(h) + f(n));

  printf("%f\n", sum);

  second =  (4.0f) * h * f(a);
  }
  printf("second sum: %f\n",second );

  sum = sum + first + second;
  printf("%f\n", sum); 
  return 0;
}
```

The answer should be around 3.1 (The value of the final `sum`)

Comment: what is the problem exactly ?

Comment: What should the initial values of first and second be? What are they on you're current code?

Comment: Why are you printing your `float` values with `%d` instead of `%f` ?

Comment: oh ya, I fixed it. The loops has different values now, but still doesn't provide the correct answer.

Comment: nvm, I see my mistake now.

Comment: After multiple edits the posted code now exhibits exactly *none* of the original posted problems and the question has reduced to "debug this for me please". vtc.

Comment: There is code outside functions. That's not allowed in C.

Comment: I figured it out now. I think the main problem I was having is I forgot about the `.0f`

Comment: Don't "fix" questions! Also, this code won't compile.

Comment: why are you using for loops anyway, first =  (2.0f) * h * f(a ); is not influenced by any iterator and you don't accumulate the result, you are simply computing it several times over...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your divisions won't probably do what you expect:

```
(2 / 3) == 0
```

Dividing `int` with `int` will result in `int`.

Use float constants `(2.0f / 3.0f)`

**Edit:**

You still have the same problem with the other `n / 2`.

And you should use `%f` when printing floats: `printf("first sum: %f\n",first);`

[The value of the integral is: 3.109337](http://ideone.com/e.js/Zfwn3S)

Comment: I don't know if it's intended, but you might have the same problem with `(n / 2)`.

Comment: that's ok. The first and second loop still have the same value... Try out the code yourself.